# Enter the room with the game in progress

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

How can I check if the master has already started the room, and send new players straight into the game?

I'm doing this for all players after the lobby goes into the game.

```
  [PunRPC]
  public void Game(string name)
  {
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(name);
  }
```

And to enter the lobby

```
public void JoinRoom(string nameRoom)
  {
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(nameRoom);
  }
```

But how can I know if the master has already started the room? To send the player straight into the game rather than the lobby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a Custom Property value. But there are multiple ways to do this. Check out the [Synchronization and State doc](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/synchronization-and-state) and read up on how to sync the loaded level.